# Lambda function using Layers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, firebase-admin, aws-lambda-layers

New to AWS Layer, trying to use Layer as dependency for my Lambda function. However knock on this issue `"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"`, could anyone point out my mistake?

Below's what I did:

1. Zipped and uploaded my Firebase-Admin dependency to Lambda via CLI. In the zip it contains (node_modules, package-lock.json, pacakage.json)
2. On my Lambda function I have set to use the Layer with version specified via AWS GUI.

**Code on my Lambda function**

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("../maskedPath.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://maskedProject.firebaseio.com"
  });

var registrationToken = 'maskedToken';

exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
    var message = {
        data: {
          score: '850',
          time: '2:45'
        },
        token: registrationToken
      };

    admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
}
```

3. Execute function with an empty test case `{}`
4. Issue as below:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11"
  ]
}
```

I have also tried to configure the my lambda function to use the layer via CLI with the line of code below, result was `"LastUpdateStatus": "Successful"`

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name maskedData --layers arn:aws:lambda:maskedData:layer:maskedData:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the reason why, apparently it requires an extra folder layer.

> To include libraries in a layer, place them in one of the folders supported by your runtime.

For different language used in Lambda, you should have an extra layer of folder with different name. For my case I created nodejs folder and move node_modules inside, then re-upload it as 2nd version.

```
xray-sdk.zip

└ nodejs/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk
```

Read more on: [Including Library Dependencies in a Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Comment: I have the same problem. My folder structure is exactly as required yet I get the same problem. I am also trying to use the firebase-admin sdk. Can you kindly let me know what I'm missing here? 
nodejs